How to create new fields in one feature named after the values in another feature's field (based on a spatial join)
I am working in ArcGIS Pro.
I have created a fishnet layer over an area of interest. I have another layer that has text a field called 'main_rock' that records different types of geological units in the area. (see screenshot)

I want to add new fields to the fishnet layer's attribute table named after each unique value in the 'main_rock' field of the geology layer (e.g.'dolerite', 'granodiorate',etc.). I then want each of these new fields to be populated with a 1 or 0, based on the presence or absence of the corresponding value in the 'main_rock' field in the geology layer.
Ultimately I want to create a table that looks something like this, with each unique value in the main_rock field as its own field:

I have created an ArcPy script which accomplishes this task using a Spatial Join. This only partially works, however, as the spatial join only captures the first value in the join feature (rather than all values that occur within each fishnet cell) and therefore a 1 gets put in only that field in the output.
I need it to work the following way: If a single cell of the fishnet intersects with multiple types of rock in the join feature, a new field is created for each type of rock, and a 1 is placed in each one.
I think this could be accomplished by concatenating all of the values in FieldMappings with a delimiter, and then modifying the subsequent code so that it creates a new field in the output feature for each unique value in that field, and then populates those new fields with a 1 or 0 based on whether the field name is IN the concatenated field (rather than matches). However, I can't figure out how to make that work.
Here is the current state of my ArcPy script:
import arcpy

# Set the workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "My_Workspace"

# Allow overwriting of output files
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

feature_class = "Fishnet_500m_ASMA_test"  # Feature class name
join_feature_class = "Geological_units_test"  # Join feature class name

# Define the field name to use
geodiv_field = "main_rock"

# Create a FieldMappings object
field_mappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()

# Create a FieldMap for the geodiversity field
field_map = arcpy.FieldMap()
field_map.addInputField(join_feature_class, geodiv_field)  # Add the geodiv_field from the join feature class

# Add the FieldMap to the FieldMappings
field_mappings.addFieldMap(field_map)

# Create the output feature class name by combining the feature class and join feature class names
output_feature_class = f"{feature_class}_joined_{join_feature_class}"  # Output feature class name

# Perform the spatial join with the FieldMappings
arcpy.analysis.SpatialJoin(target_features=feature_class, 
                            join_features=join_feature_class, 
                            out_feature_class=output_feature_class, 
                            field_mapping=field_mappings, 
                            match_option="INTERSECT")

# Get unique values from the geodiversity field
unique_values = set()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(output_feature_class, [geodiv_field]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] is not None:
            unique_values.add(row[0])

# Create new fields based on unique geodiversity values
for value in unique_values:
    field_name = value.replace(" ", "_").replace("-", "_")  # Replace spaces and hyphens with underscores
    if field_name not in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(output_feature_class)]:
        arcpy.AddField_management(output_feature_class, field_name, "SHORT")

# Start an edit session
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(output_feature_class, [geodiv_field] + list(unique_values)) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # Get the field value from the geodiversity field
        field_value = row[0]  # Value from the geodiv_field

        # Initialize all new fields to 0
        for i in range(1, len(row)):
            row[i] = 0

        # Check if field_value is not None before checking for membership
        if field_value is not None:
            # Set the corresponding field to 1 if the field name matches
            field_name = field_value.replace(" ", "_").replace("-", "_")  # Replace spaces and hyphens with underscores
            if field_name in cursor.fields:
                row[cursor.fields.index(field_name)] = 1  # Set to 1 if the field name matches
        
        # Update the row
        cursor.updateRow(row)

print("Field calculation completed.")



There are lots of ways to accomplish this.  Why don't you get started with a model builder model and report back when you encounter specific problems?

As @GBG states in the comments this could be achieved in multiple ways. I present a simple model that does this.  The Master model is this:
It does a spatial join with a 1:M relationship, I set field mappings to show only the GridID field and geology field

The sub model is this:
I iterate over fields of type long, this avoids ObjectID but includes the GridID field and the Join_FID fields

The Calculate field tool is set up as is:

The Code block is here for convenience:
def update(FieldName, gridID, fieldValue):
    if FieldName == "GridID":
        return gridID
    else:
        if fieldValue is None:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1

The pivot tool creates fields of either NULL values or the FID, which are recoded to 1 or 0. GridID is the field name I used in my fishnet to number each cell.
Inputs:

Output:


Thanks this seems to work well, except that I had to delete the "1" before "update" in the Calculate Field tool settings:
update("%Field%", !GridID!, !%Field%!)

Is there a way to modify the model so that the output table contains the area of each feature within each grid cell, rather than presence/absence (1/0)?
